# Confusion about Partial Derivative for a Function of One Variable

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

This question actually came up as I was reading an example in my differential equations book (Boyce & Diprima):

> Solve: $2x+y^2+2xyy'=0$
>
> Define $\psi(x,y)=x^2+xy^2$
>
> Then $$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=2x+y^2, \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}=2xy$$
>
> The differential equation is then $$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Here's what I don't understand:
$y$ is a function of $x$ - assume it's one-to-one. $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$, by definition, is computed for $y$ held constant. If $y$ is a function of $x$, if $y$ is held constant, $x$ must be constant too - what then is the meaning of $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi$ is actually defined on $\mathbb R^2$; the author could have written 
$$
\phi: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R: (a, b) \mapsto a^2 + a b^2
$$

The problem is that our notation for derivatives depends on the choice of "dummy variables" that we use in denoting a function (sigh...on the good side, it often makes the chain rule work out in really nifty ways).

If, instead of $\partial \phi/\partial x$, you'd accept the notation $\partial_1 \phi$ to indicate "partial derivative with respect to the first argument", then you have

$$
\partial_1 \phi(a, b) = 2a + b^2 
$$
or
$$
\partial_1 \phi(x, y) = 2x + y^2 
$$
or even
$$
\partial_1 \phi(x, y(x)) = 2x + y(x)^2 
$$
where $y$ is some function of the single variable $x$.

Comment: First, do you mean the codomain is $\mathbb{R^1}$ (You wrote $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$)? Second, I can see how this partial derivative is calculated "formally" by assuming $\psi$'s domain is $\mathbb R^2$, but I'm having trouble understanding how to interpret it (maybe I missed your point). Because if $y$ is a function of $x$, then $\psi$ is really just a function of $x$ only, isn't it?

Comment: @FreshAir Once $y$ is made into a function of $x$, $\psi$ becomes a function of just $x$, yes. However, we need to use the chain rule to compute the *total* derivative of $\psi$ with respect to $x$ (which is what $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$ is). This is indeed the whole point: once you see that the equation is $\frac{d \psi}{dx}=0$, you see that the solutions form the level sets of $\psi$. This is the whole idea behind exact equations.

Comment: Yes -- the $R^2$ was an error...fixed. As for the second part, this is actually a subtle use of the chain rule, and Boyce and DiPrima are being pretty glib in not giving any further explanation. But it's NOT just a 'formal derivative; I've computed the partials of $\phi$ as a real-valued function on the plane. [And I now realize it should have been $\psi$ -- sorry!] The *real* question is "What does that last sentence --- "The diferential equation is then ..." --- actually mean?" Everything before that is just the chain rule.

Comment: @FreshAir It may be helpful to no longer think of $y$ as a function of $x$ but to instead think of $x$ and $y$ as both being functions of a third variable, say $t$. Then in the cases where we want $y(x)$, we consider $x$ to be a trivial function of $t$: $x(t)=t$. This is one way of making the "exact differential" notation $f_x dx + f_y dy = 0$ precise: instead it becomes $f_x \frac{dx}{dt} + f_y \frac{dy}{dt} = 0$.

Comment: JohnHughes & Ian, this is tremendously helpful. This may be a bit trivial, but I wondered if all level curves, i.e. $x^2+xy^2=$const, can be parameterized by $t$. I think the answer is yes - implying any function $y$ satisfying $x^2+xy^2=$const is a solution.

Comment: Then I wondered if $x^2+xy^2=$const constitutes a complete solution set (have we found all the solutions?) Since $\frac{d \psi}{dx}=0$ iff $2x+y^2+2xyy'=0$, I think the answer is again "yes".

Comment: I believe you are correct, and have now untangle all that B & dP *should* have written down. :)